# How to hide elements which go beyond the canvas in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

Is there a way to hide the elements which span beyond the canvas area (artboard) in Sketch?

[image: Sketch elements beyond canvas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

**All layers should be placed inside the "canvas"** or "artboard" layer.

E.g. If you start the document with the iPad Landscape template, all of your objects should stay inside of that layer, otherwise they can bleed out.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a mask to hide the parts you don't want.

Comment: Could you please include how to do so in your answer?